# How do I use eps in this situation where I am taking differences of cumulative sums

Tags: matlab, double, precision

First, the data:

```
orig = reshape([0.0000000000000000 0.3480000000000000 0.7570000000000000 1.3009999999999999 2.8300000000000001 4.7519999999999998 5.2660000000000000 5.8120000000000003 14.3360000000000000 15.3390000000000000 ],[10   1])

change = reshape([0.0000000000000000 0.3480000000000000 0.0000000000000000 0.9530000000000000 1.5290000000000001 1.9219999999999997 0.5140000000000002 0.5460000000000003 0.0000000000000000 9.5270000000000010 ],[10   1])

change = cumsum(change)
```

`orig` is a vector of seconds elapsed. `change` is a vector derived by taking differences between (some) elements of `orig`. The cumulative sum of `change` has some elements actually equal to the corresponding element in `orig`.

However, due to precision issues:

```
diff = orig - change
```

gives

```
diff =

                         0
                         0
                     0.409
                         0
                         0
                         0
                         0
                         0
                     8.524
     -1.77635683940025e-15
```

It seems that if I run the following command:

```
diff(abs(diff) <= eps(orig)) = 0
```

then this sets entries which should be zero, but are not due to precision issues, to be zero.

My question is, is this the correct way to do it? Why is the comparison `<=` instead of `<`? Should the statement be:

```
diff(abs(diff) < k*eps(orig)) = 0
```

for some `k > 1` to give some tolerance? If so, how would one pick `k`?

---

In case it is necessary to know how `change` is derived from `orig`, the following alternate example also shows this behaviour:

```
orig = reshape([0.0000000000000000 0.3480000000000000 0.7570000000000000 1.3009999999999999 2.8300000000000001 4.7519999999999998 5.2660000000000000 5.8120000000000003 14.3360000000000000 15.3390000000000000 ],[10   1])
change = orig - [0; orig(1:end-1)]
change = cumsum(change)
diff = orig - change
```

Comment: `diff` is a built-in function. Please don't use these kind of names for your variables. It can lead to unexpected or unintended behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The following statement will be true only if the "almost zero" happens because 1 bit is offseted.

```
abs(diff) <= eps(orig)
```

1 bit is a ridiculously high precision to ask, a precision that most likely you can not achieve. Generally, you need to define your treshold yourself, such as

```
abs(diff) <= 1e-12
```

You also ask how to choose this value. Answer: there is no way we can tell you that. Its algorithm, application, unit, computer, [...] specific.

You are computing distance between particles? Maybe you need a smaller tolerance. You are doing economic profit calculus? 1e-12 is then a decimal you won't get in cash, for sure. Use 1e-4 instead. Or are you using an algorithm that does numerical approximations? Then you need a higher tolerance. How much tolerance you are OK with is, and will always be, a user choice.

---

Note: you need to be aware of the types you are using to set this minimum threshold right. MATLAB uses `double` as default, but if you are using other types, them this threshold is too strict. As an alternative, you can use

```
abs(diff) <= 100*eps(class(diff))
```

If your data type is not fixed/known.

Comment: I don't like this answer. The `eps` is a function that generates the value based on the type and system. I.e. `eps('single')` for me is around `1e-07`, and your hard-coded value won't work.

Comment: @Bernhard But the OP is not using it with different types. I can add information about types if needed. The OP is using `eps`' functionality as "the smallest difference between numbers at this scale", thus, 1 bit offset between what he wants and has. Personally, I believe that hardcoding your tolerances is the best way of ensuring you know whats going on. Whats your alternative? `eps('double')` is too small, then `eps('double')*100`. How is this better than my answer?

Comment: Well, @Alex especially asks about the factor `k`. What determines the error you can expect?  Why would you set `k` any larger then necessary? I am interested in a general answer to this question. The factor 100 now is just as arbitrary, but is there a choice that really makes sense, based on known limitations?

Comment: @Bernhard No there is no choice that really makes sense. The choice of tolerances are always user made, depending on the problem, desired accuracy etc. Generally, one uses the tolerance to decide if you are "close enough". Depends what a unit of that is, what algorithm for numerical solving you use and the application. There is no general answer for the choice of tolerance.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, `orig` starts at 0 and finishes around 100000. In this case `eps(orig)` automatically scales the smallest unit to be of a suitable scale to match the smallest and biggest number of orig.

Comment: also, is the one bit precision unreasonable to expect when the second vector is a cumulative sum of the differences of the first vector? that is what it comes down to.

Comment: @Alex One bit precision is virtually impossible to achieve with numerical methods.

Comment: yet, doing the fix I proposed removed all negative small differences which are meant to be zero. So, in my case, for whatever reason, it worked, I should note that this calculation is done over 20 million lines of time stamps.

Comment: @Alex in your case it works because they are defined exactly equally just before the error checking. This will not be the case, almost never. Use my technique as a general solution

Comment: i don't understand that last comment.

Comment: @Alex I'd need 2h of lectures to get into the depths of numerical precission in computers to explain everything properly. The message to take home: compare `abs(error)<1e-10`, thats the good way of doing it.